# Angularjs for large web application

Tags: angularjs

Would angularjs be suitable  to handle large scale web application? Is reliable enough for  good performance at scale ?

Comment: something like avvo.com

Answer (score 1):

Its depend on your requirement. As `Angular` is the best for CRUD application, if your application doesn't have too much complexity then you can surely go with `Angular`. If you required too much DOM manipulation which usually requires for gaming app then Angular can be painful.

**Is Angular slow?**

Well, In some cases, you may feel that angular is very slow. Specially when you iterate over the complex JSON then there may be too much data binding so angular gets slow after 2500+ watches.

There are lots of directive to overcome this problem. Also day by day Angular itself updating their library to solve these kind of problems. Some of the directives which is helpful to improve performance of Angular are as below:

- [Angular Once](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once)
- [Angular InView](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview)
- [Quick ng-repeat Directive](https://github.com/allaud/quick-ng-repeat) (Customized ng-repeat directive)
- [Karl Seamon's saying about Angular Performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyYpHIOrk_Y)

**Points that should be clear in mind while using Angular for Large Application**

The best feature of `Angular` can be painful if you don't implement it in a right way. if you are new to angular and you have worked with jQuery then first of all you need to change your thinking towards problems to Angular way rather than jQuery. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

- [Angular Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)
- [Angular Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Simply, you must be clear about the basic concepts of an `Angular` to use it properly. Angular also gives amazing feature of unit testing. You should write tests for each smaller chunks of your code.

I'm fan of angular. It's awesome. I would surely recommend you `AngularJS`.

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to your definition of a large web application. As Angular is modular by design and integrates seemlessly out of the box with unit testing in that regard its great for large web applications.

Angular is a framework for building applications and once you get it more or less right your benefits pop right out at you. Try doing similar things with jQuery or even Backbone and you will have problems (jQuery might be an unfair comparison, unless we speak of the ability to organize modular code easily).

This is a great [article](https://coderwall.com/p/y0zkiw) that outlines angular in large applications.

Also from wunderkind Brian Ford this [article](http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps.html).